# How to update markers on the MapView?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I've added a few markers to my MapView:

```
List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
Drawable drawable;
MapOverlay itemizedOverlay;

mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_dot_green);
itemizedOverlay = new MapOverlay(drawable, mapView);
GeoPoint markerPoint = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(markerPoint, "name", "description");
itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
```

Now I need to change markers (`drawables`) regularly for them. I am planning to use `Runnable` for this. But how can I replace the markers?

Upd. here is the current code for the same:

```
public class Map extends MapActivity {
    private MapOverlay itemizedOverlay;
    private MapView mapView;

private Runnable mUpdateMapMarkers = new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
       Drawable drawable_green = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_dot_green);
       int w = drawable_green.getIntrinsicWidth();
       int h = drawable_green.getIntrinsicHeight();
       drawable_green.setBounds(-w / 2, -h, w / 2, 0);

       for (int i = 0; i < itemizedOverlay.size(); i++) {
         itemizedOverlay.getItem(i).setMarker(drawable_green);
       }
       mapView.invalidate();

         mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateMapMarkers, 5*60*1000); // once in 5 minutes   
     }
  };
```

Comment: how u achiveed ? http://pastie.org/10232768 here is the code its not updating line on mapview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use `LevelListDrawables` and change the level, or create your own `OverlayItem` subclass and override `getMarker()`. [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/ILuvNooYawk) demonstrates the latter approach.

Comment: Looks like `LevelListDrawables` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html) is the easiest option. But how can I get access to all markers at my `Runnable`? Also, since `LevelListDrawables` changes the drawable, not marker, how should I change that for marker? Apply `setMarker` again?

Comment: "But how can I get access to all markers at my Runnable?" -- I have no idea what you are referring to. "Also, since LevelListDrawables changes the drawable, not marker, how should I change that for marker?" -- possibly, or `invalidate()` if needed.

Comment: "But how can I get access to all markers at my Runnable?" - let's say I have 5 markers added to the map. How can I access each of them? Should I keep `itemizedOverlay` as class variable and then use `getItem` (http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay.html#getItem(int))?

Comment: If I follow 2nd approach - I am not sure when `getMarker()` is called. Looks like it called only when it should shown on the map. How can call it each 5 minutes (if user is not touching map and not moving, i.e. map display is not changed)?

Comment: For a timer-based update, try calling `invalidate()` on the `MapView`. after updating the `LevelListDrawable`. That's a bit like swatting a fly with a Buick, but it should work. Once you get it working, you can perhaps poke around and see if you can invalidate a smaller area for better performance, if needed.

Comment: "Should I keep itemizedOverlay as class variable" -- if by "class variable" you mean "a static data member", then heavens, no. If by "class variable" you mean "a regular data member of my `MapActivity`", then yes.

Comment: I've updated the question with the code - it works. Is it efficient approach?

Comment: Other than the cost of `invalidate()` -- and I haven't ever really tried that on a `MapView` -- that seems OK for a modest number of `OverlayItems`. If it feels OK to you, then it is probably OK for the user.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I have last question related to markers update. Is there any way to define additional data for each marker (for ex., unique id) - it will help me to identify the marker. Or, should I use marker's location (lat and lng) for the same?

Comment: You can extend `OverlayItem` and hold whatever you want.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'd a similar issue, what if I needed to change an ItemizedOverlay which is already been show, how can I reupdate that particular overlayItem? For example, i've 5 items and more coming realtime...and i want to change the previous 5 items depending on next incoming overlayItems. How do I do it?

I'm using the same holder how you have done, and I tried setMarker of the ArrayList but nothing, and also then tried to set the ArrayList with new OverlayMarker but nothing worked. Any help please?